# Rendering textual value for numeric in Layout

Tags: page-layout

My account object has a field which is numeric and represents a code of economic activity. I'd like to display to end-users a textual value i,e, "Financial Services" instead of 048. What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Depends on how many possible codes there are?

Comment: About one hundred

Comment: in that case I would have a lookup to records of "Economic Activity" that contains the code. The lookup would display the name. If you need the code you could pull it in via a formula field. this is just one way to do it. A formula would be unmanageable.

Comment: Are you suggesting to create a custom object for a key-value pair mapping?

Comment: Unless you want to do it via code or some monster PB yes. Much easier to maintain than a formula but does add some overhead for users to populate if they are doing it manually